# .Finding the closes element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a dropdown menu I'm working on. I've added a hidden icon on each item. Then once the menu generates, I want to go through and find which items have sub-menus and remove the `hidden` class for those items.

I can't seem to be able to get this code working.

```
    var tags = $("li > ul.sub-menu").each(function(){
      $(this).parent("li").closest('i.hidden').removeClass("hidden")
    })
```

This is the html/css

http://pastebin.com/FzTFeYMq

I'm using IE8 so right now I can't get a proper fiddle up.

Comment: what do you get when you console.log($(this).closest('i.hidden'))

Comment: `closest()` looks _up_ the parent chain, not for siblings, children or other nodes.

Comment: `closest()` looks through the ancestors of an element, and an `<i>` element should not contain a `<ul>`; perhaps you meant to use `find()` to search through the descendants? Without your HTML we're unable to offer anything more than guesses.

Comment: btw, you are not the real Batman.  The real Batman would have tasked Alfred to find out :)

Comment: The html is in the pastebin

Comment: Try find() instead of closest().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, what you're trying to do is unhide the carets for any menu/submenu that has children. The following should accomplish what you're looking for:

```
var tags = $(".sub-menu").each(function(){
 $(this).closest('li').find('a > span > i:first').removeClass("hidden")
})
```

I tossed up a quick CodePen demonstrating this here: http://codepen.io/P1xt/pen/eZMLrq

Comment: Hey, it's working. I misunderstood how closest worked completely. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your loop you have to find the first element with a statement like this:

```
 $(this).find('i.hidden:first')
```